# Bill Frisell's Blues Dream

Tags: chord-progressions, jazz, blues

So I'm trying to learn this song and I was hoping you guys could help me "understand" it if that makes sense.

Here is the version of the song I'm going off of on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GenlDkfC6wM). And here's a transcription of the song I found that seems to be pretty accurate:
[image]

Its a blues in F, but the changes are almost like they would be for a blues in D (D G A). So instead of I IV V it becomes VI II III. Is that an appropriate way to think about it? Because that would make it not really a blues right? Its not a common chord progression is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still a type of I-IV-V progression, you're just in a minor key (D minor) instead of a major key (F major). The VI-II-III in actuality is a i(Dm)-iv(Gm)-V(A7).

There's more then one flavor of blues progressions and this one is derived from typical [minor blues progression patternes](http://www.premierguitar.com/articles/19366-beyond-blues-playing-the-right-minor-blues-changes).

Comment: Just to make it more clear, every time signature corresponds to 2 keys. A major one and a (relative) minor one. In this case, the Major key is F and the Minor one is D